# Using Core Data with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

I'm making progress learning SwiftUI but I'm getting stuck when it comes to using it with Core Data.

- Model Objects - I made a couple of entities with the required properties and relationships
- ??? I have no idea where to begin. How to I get SwiftUI talking to Core Data?
- SwiftUI - I have some basic layouts working and showing data from some temp classes, but these have no awareness of Core Data

I've spend the last few days searching and reading everything I can on this topic but I have no idea how to begin to solve this.

Can anyone outline the basic steps to using Core Data with SwiftUI?

### Update:

I got some additional feedback on Twitter and one dev suggested that SwiftUI lists may not be suitable for working with Core Data with large data sets. Read the post here: https://twitter.com/numist/status/1141012785825845248

Here is the approach I'm going to take in my app.

- List Views:

  - UITableViewController (with a FetchedResultsController)
  - Manage the connection to Core Data store
  - Use dependency injection to pass records to a detail view
- Detail / Edit Views:

  - When possible build these with UIHostingController
  - Use SwiftUI Forms to make simple data entry forms
  - Receive data via dependency injection
  - Copy data to a temporary BindableObject type

    - Make local UI chances to the temp record
    - Save the temp data back to the actual record on exit

### Update 2 - 2019.08.14

Xcode beta 5 has some new Core Data features. I used the information in this [blog post](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/blog/ios-development/data-persistence/using-core-data-with-swiftui-introduction/) to get most of what I need.

Comment: Since there was no comment, I can only assume that my answer below was not appropriate for some reason, so I deleted it.

If you are still looking for some hints and tips on how to use CoreData with SwiftUI and need a place to start, check out my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348127/swiftui-coredata-master-detail-with-editing-xcode-11-beta-5/57533494#57533494

Comment: @ChuckH Sorry, I never even saw your answer. You sample project looks pretty awesome though.

Answer (score 6):

You can write a wrapper for your Core-Data logic, like EntityManager and then use it inside BindableObject

```
class PersonStore: BindableObject {
  var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

  var persons: [PersonEntity] = [] {
      didSet {
          didChange.send(())
      }
  }

  func fetchPersons(matching name: String) {
    // make you core data query here and assign it to persons property
  }
}
```

As soon as you query finish and value assigned to persons property SwiftUI will reload View to read new values.